# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

[image: Screenshot]

I get the `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` but I can't find the error. I'm using Laravel 5.4.

I ran `php artisan route:list` command and I see the defined (named) route.

[image: Route List]

And here is the route file.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'LinkController@create');

Route::post('/create', 'LinkController@store');

Route::get('show/{id}', 'LinkController@show')->name('show');
```

And here is the part from the resource controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'url' => 'required|url'
    ]);

    // Generate string length of 6 characters
    $newHash = Str::random(6);

    // creates a $link object
    $link = new Link;

    //checks if link already exists in the database
    $link_in_db = DB::table('links')->where('url', '=', $request->url)->get();

    if($link_in_db === null){
        // sets the $link variables
        $link->url = $request->url;
        $link->hash = $newHash;

        // $link is saved in the database
        $link->save();

        // redirects to the route
        return redirect()->route('show', $link->id);
    }else{ // link is in the database
        // print_r($link_in_db); // testing purposes
        return redirect()->route('show', $link->id);
    }
}
```

And I highly appreciate any suggestion. If there are any other methods to redirect with data, please suggest.

Thank you!

Comment: Whenever you use post method it will look for csrf token you have to use csrf in the form which is used to post. If CSRF token not found then it returns the error. You can use get method if you don't want to use csrf token

Comment: Sorry, it was "get" method. I was trying everything. So I changed it to post. Still not working. Same error.

Comment: in `else` instead of `return redirect()->route('show', $link->id);` use `return redirect()->route('show', $link_in_db->id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show` route should be `GET`:

```
Route::get('show/{id}', 'LinkController@show')->name('show');
```

Comment: Sorry, it was "get" method. I was trying everything. So I changed it to post. Still not working. Same error.

Comment: @Isuru set it to the `get` again and clear route cache with `php artisan route:clear`. Also, make sure `$link->id` outputs correct ID.

Answer (score 3):

If you define a variable on a route, you *must* provide it unless you make it optional.

```
Route::get('show/{id?}', 'LinkController@show');
```

will make the id segment optional and route `/show` to the method with a null value in id.

Essentially you do not have a route set up for `/show` you have a route set up for `/show/somethinghere`